# .each Statement Based on Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, relationship, each, nested-resources

I am trying to write an .each statement based on the characteristic of a nested resource. The relationships between tables in my app are defined as below:

```
User has_many Posts
Post belongs_to User
Post belongs_to Category
Category has_many Posts
```

From a page for a given category I would like to index all Users who have a post in that category. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have been experimenting with various forms of the following statement but have not been successful.

`<% User.where(user.post.category == @category).each do |category| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller:

```
@users = User.joins(:post).where(posts: {category_id: @category.id})
```

In view

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <Your html code>
<% end %>
```

Always keep your business logic out of views. It would be suggested making that query as a scope in the model.

In user.rb

```
scope :post_users, -> (category_id)  {joins(:post).where(posts: {category_id: category_id})}
```

In controller

```
@post_users = User.post_users(@category.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can search users with query below and then list it

```
<% @users = User.joins(:posts).where('posts.category_id = ?',@category.id) %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```

#### note: you can put line 1 above in your controller

Comment: It would be better to define @users in the controller action than in the view. We should try to keep as much logic as possible away from views.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to set the `@users` in controller method or make any **helper method** to get the result in the view

```
def your_method ## or any other method
  .....
  .....
  @users = User.joins(:posts).where('posts.category_id = ?',@category.id)
end
```

And then in view

```
#your_view.html.erb

<% @users.each do |user| %>
<% end %>
```